# Can't use itemFromIndex in clicked signal of QTreeView with QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: qt

I have a QTreeView with a QSortFilterProxyModel between the view and a QStandardItemModel to sort the tree.  I then want to act on clicks in the view through the clicked() signal.

The models/view are setup similar to this:

```
mymodel  = new QStandardItemModel(5, 5, this);
mysort = new MySortProxy(this);
mysort->setSourceModel(mymodel);
myview = new QTableView(this);
myview->setSourceModel(mysort);
connect(myview, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, slot(clickAction(QModelIndex)));
```

This setup all works and sorts my data in the way I want it.  When you click on an item, the clickAction() slot gets called with the index of the item clicked.  I then try to get the item from the index in the slot:

```
void myclass::clickAction(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QStandardItem *item = mymodel->itemFromIndex(index);
}
```

However, itemFromIndex returns NULL.

If I remove the QSortFilterProxyModel and set the model directly as sourcemodel in the view, it all works perfectly.  I.e.

```
myview->setSourceModel(mymodel);    // was setSourceModel(mysort);
```

mymodel->itemFromIndex(index) now returns the item as expected, but obviously now I can't use my own sort proxy.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can get the item in the click slot when I have a sortfilter proxy in place?

I'm using Qt-4.3.1.

Thanks for any help, Giles

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like:

```
void myclass::clickAction(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QStandardItem *item = mymodel->itemFromIndex(mysort->mapToSource(index));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  Unfortunately I can't try this until Tuesday now as Monday is a bank holiday in England.  However, your answer rings a lot of bells and I'm sure will prove to be correct so I will mark it as accepted now.  I'll update this after I've tried it on Tuesday.  Thanks.