# QTableWidget original index sorting

Tags: qt

I am using QTableWidget and when the user clicks on a particular row, I use that index to perform some operation. I have also enabled sorting using setSortEnable, so when I sort it by clicking on a header, all row index change but I want previous index so what should I do?

Comment: I can't parse what exactly is being asked.  Please clarify what is happening, and what you want to have happen.

Comment: in QTableWidget i finally want is index which first ever seted when i opened table even after sorting table according to any column ....

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the unsorted index so you can map that back to some external list of data? If that is the case, then you should use a QTableView() which will allow you to setup a sort proxy and map indexes back to your original data (model).

This question has some info that may help: [Can't use itemFromIndex in clicked signal of QTreeView with QSortFilterProxyModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586718/cant-use-itemfromindex-in-clicked-signal-of-qtreeview-with-qsortfilterproxymodel)

Comment: actually i have one QVector which contain Qstringlist for indivisual row so write now what i am doing is taking whole selected row and use isContain method of QVector (but i dont think its right way to check it out) and taking the index from QVector